# Cordova Windows 10 navbar overlapping

Tags: cordova, windows-10, navbar

I built a cordova application for WP 10.0 (universal windows).
When running it on my device that doesn't have hardware buttons (Lumia 950), the HTML content is overlapped by the navbar and webview doesn't seems to calculate the real height size.

Is it possible to prevent this overlapping?

INFO : One similar subject is already opened, but only for WP 8.1 and doesn't work using Windows 10 platform : [Cordova/Phonegap: WP8.1 Navbar overlapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29342517/cordova-phonegap-wp8-1-navbar-overlapping)

EDIT : Created an issue on Cordova issue tracker. I hope to have an answer and an idea to resolve it : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-12504